# Can I write Debug Layer messages to stderr in Direct3D11?

Tags: direct3d11

I am currently trying to make a small console application that uses Direct3D11 to render images from HLSL.

Direct3D11 emits a lot of useful information to the debug layer, which I can access running under a debugger, but I would like to be able to access these when running the program normally, ideally by printing them to stderr.

I can't find any documentation to suggest this is possible even in principle, and am hoping I'm wrong. Any suggestions as to how I might do this?

Comment: I didn't see a way to capture the messages through D3D, but perhaps you can instead act as the debug window and capture all messages written to `OutputDebugString`?

Comment: It's not a particularly common thing to implement, but you can in theory do it with [ID3D11InfoQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476538(v=vs.85).aspx) using a retrieval-filter.